# Display Apple Watch heart rate continuously on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

During a work out using the Apple Watch native workout app, is there a way to display the Apple Watch heart rate data continuously on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can with 3rd party apps, like Cardiogram. The realtime-ness of it won't be instant as it has to sync the data with your phone but it is continuous.(see Cardiogram article [[Apple Watch] What does the option of ‘Continuous recording' mean?](https://help.cardiogram.com/article/31-what-does-the-option-of-continuous-reading-mean))

> 'Continuous recording' allows your Apple watch to collect a heart rate reading every 5 seconds. It is similar to starting a workout on your Apple Watch.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to use the native workout app. Apparently there's a way to duplicate the watch's face in real time on the phone. I need to look into that.